# Unable to get today's records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check whether any record already exists in the table or not by today's date and my `sql-server` is in USA.

I tried the next query but im getting 0 records, eventhough there is 23 records in the table of today date.

insertion code

```cs
public void InsertSmsDetails()
{
    DateTime today = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
    string usecase = "manhole_Chennai";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sms (updtd_date,usecase,sms) values ('" + today + "','" + usecase + "','"+TempData["SMSBody"].ToString()+"')", con);
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

query to get data

```
SELECT * 
FROM   SMS 
where  updtd_date > CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) 
and    usecase = 'manhole_Chennai'
```

Note that `updtd_date` column is of type `datetime`

Sample data:

```
2018-03-05 12:35:15.000 manhole_Chennai 11383   Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09   NULL    NULL
2018-03-05 12:34:40.000 manhole_Chennai 11382   Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09   NULL    NULL
2018-03-05 12:34:07.000 manhole_Chennai 11381   Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09   NULL    NULL
2018-03-05 12:33:33.000 manhole_Chennai 11380   Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09   NULL    NULL
2018-03-05 12:32:58.000 manhole_Chennai 11379   Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09   NULL    NULL
2018-03-05 12:32:21.000 manhole_Chennai 11378   Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09   NULL    NULL
```

[image: table]

Comment: Do a simple `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` and see what value it returns. This might be a problem with timezone differences.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].
Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: @EzLo its returing - 2018-05-03

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, check the link to rexterster in my answer.

Comment: Your data says `5th of March` and you're asking for data newer than `3rd of May`. Probably that's the issue?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Good catch!

Comment: As says @EvaldasBuinauskas, you may have multiple problems there. All of them caused by not proper data type usage. Please check your datetime formats first, and, then keep in mind - you have huge problem with India/USA time zones colision, as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the way you insert data into database using `InsertSmsDetails()` method and not the way you query it.

Your code probably generates this gem:

```
insert into sms (updtd_date, usecase, sms)
values ('03/05/2018','manhole_Chennai 11383','Alert : Manhole is filled 6.41666666666667 at time02/05/2018 16:11:09');
```

And your date `'03/05/2018'` is inserted as a string and misinterpreted as 5th of March due to US locale.

So the right way to fix this would be changing the way you persist your data and also changing the way you store your timestamps. There are a couple of options:

1. Store timestamps in UTC
2. Use `datetimeoffset` datatype which will include timezone information on it.

Answer (score 1):

You request records GREATER than today date

If you want the records for today :

```
SELECT * 
FROM SMS 
where CAST(updtd_date) = CAST(getdate())   
  and usecase ='manhole_Chennai'
```

Records for today and future :

```
SELECT * FROM SMS where updtd_date >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) and usecase ='manhole_Chennai'
```

Comment: both queries not returning any data. 0 records found with these query

Comment: if  `previous`  then  `where updtd_date <=CONVERT(date,GetDATE())`

Comment: No, `updtd_date` is `datetime, meaning for today's date it's value will only be equal to `convert(date, getdate())` at midnight.

Comment: @ZoharPeled right, I missed the datetime type. I fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Your current query should return all records where `updtd_date` is today **or later**.
To prevent getting future records you need to add another condition.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    updtd_date datetime
)

INSERT INTO @T (updtd_date) VALUES
(DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())), 
(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())), 
(DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE())), 
(DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())), 
(GETDATE()), 
(DATEADD(HOUR, 1, GETDATE())), 
(DATEADD(HOUR, 2, GETDATE())), 
(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())), 
(DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE()))
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Id, 
        updtd_date
FROM @T
WHERE updtd_date > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND updtd_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
ORDER BY id
```

Results:

```
Id  updtd_date
3   03.05.2018 07:15:13
4   03.05.2018 08:15:13
5   03.05.2018 09:15:13
6   03.05.2018 10:15:13
7   03.05.2018 11:15:13
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/OKAX73985)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. You problem is simple: as I see your InsertSmsDetails() code, your code works with India time zone (hardcoded).

Then, your server is in USA. There is huge time zone diff here. Its reason, why you do not see records.

To solve your problem, you cannot use GETDATE(), as it returns USA datetime. Your table data is saved with India datetime offset in mind. At this case, you need to generalize both datetimes to be comparable.

Let say, your hadrdcoded India Standard Time datetime offset is UTC +5:30 (or +330 in mins). Then you may use this, to solve your problem:

```
select 
    *
from 
    [sms]
where 
        [updtd_date]    > convert(date, switchoffset(sysdatetimeoffset(), 330))
    and [usecase]       = 'manhole_Chennai';
```

Keep in mind, you will have potential problems on summer/winter time switching. So, try to modify your code to save all dates with offset values (i.e. using datetimeoffset data type instead of datetime)